# Add video to wordpress login page

Tags: wp-login-form

i have a wordpress theme and they are using a simple template as a login page (see the image bellow) now i want to add a video just into the left side from the login form and a search box. how can i do this?

1. Video place
2. Buddypress member search box with a title

[image]

I have added the login page template coding bellow please have a look.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Login
 */
?>
<?php
 // IF USER IS ALREADY LOGGED -> REDIRECT HIM TO HOME PAGE
 if (is_user_logged_in()) :     
      wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
 exit;
 else :
 // We get the logo image
 $login_logo_image = woffice_get_settings_option('login_logo_image');
 // Second landing :
 $login_layout = woffice_get_settings_option('login_layout');

?>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> style="margin-top: 0 !important;">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <!-- MAKE IT RESPONSIVE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <?php // GET FAVICONS
    woffice_favicons();
    ?>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/flexie.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class($login_layout); ?>>

    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div id="content-container">
          <?php // Check for Revolution Slider :
            $login_revslider = woffice_get_settings_option('login_revslider');
            ?>
            <!-- START CONTENT -->
            <section id="woffice-login" class="<?php echo (!empty($login_revslider) ? 'revslider-enabled' : 'revslider-disabled') ?>">

                <div id="woffice-login-left">
                    <?php
                    // Revslider :
                    if (!empty($login_revslider) && shortcode_exists('rev_slider')) :
                        putRevSlider($login_revslider);
                    endif;
                    ?>
                </div>

                <div id="woffice-login-right">
                    <!-- LOGO & DESCRIPTION -->
                    <header>
                        <?php if (!empty($login_logo_image)) { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" id="login-logo"><img src='<?php echo $login_logo_image["url"]; ?>'/></a>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php // THE ERRORS
                        $login  = (isset($_GET['login']) ) ? $_GET['login'] : 0;
                        $color_notifications = woffice_get_settings_option('color_notifications');

                        //Display default message for plugin New User Approve
                        if(class_exists('pw_new_user_approve')) {
                            if((is_string($login) && $login == 'pending_approval')) {
                                echo'<div class="infobox fa-meh-o" style="background-color: '.$color_notifications.';">';
                                echo'<span class="infobox-head"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> '. __('ERROR:','woffice').'</span>';
                                echo'<p>'. __('Your account is still pending approval.','woffice') .'</p>';
                                echo'</div>';
                            } else {
                                echo'<div class="infobox" style="background-color: '.$color_notifications.';">';
                                echo'<p>'. __('This site is accessible to approved users only. To be approved, you must first register.','woffice') .'</p>';
                                echo'</div>';
                            }
                        }

                        if ( $login === "failed" ) {
                            echo'<div class="infobox fa-meh-o" style="background-color: '.$color_notifications.';">';
                                echo'<span class="infobox-head"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> '. __('ERROR:','woffice').'</span>';
                                echo'<p>'. __('Invalid username and/or password.','woffice') .'</p>';
                            echo'</div>';
                        } elseif ( $login === "empty" ) {
                            echo'<div class="infobox fa-meh-o" style="background-color: '.$color_notifications.';">';
                                echo'<p>'. __('Username and/or Password is empty.','woffice') .'</p>';
                            echo'</div>';
                        } elseif ( $login === "false" ) {
                            $color_notifications_green = woffice_get_settings_option('color_notifications_green');
                            echo'<div class="infobox fa-check-circle-o" style="background-color: '.$color_notifications_green.';">';
                                echo'<span class="infobox-head"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> '. __('Success:','woffice').'</span>';
                                echo'<p>'. __('You are logged out.','woffice') .'</p>';
                            echo'</div>';
                        }
                        ?>

                        <?php // GET & DISPLAY LOGIN TEXT 
                        $login_text = woffice_get_settings_option('login_text'); 
                        if (!empty($login_text)):
                            echo"<p>".$login_text."</p>";
                        endif; ?>

                        <?php /* GOOGLE LOGIN */
                        if (function_exists('woffice_glogin_frontend')){
                            woffice_glogin_frontend();
                        } ?>

                    </header>

                    <!-- FORM -->
                    <?php
                    // CHECKING FOR OTHER FORMS FIRST   
                    $type = (isset($_GET['type'])) ? $_GET['type'] : "";
                    if ($type == "lost-password") {
                        //
                        // THE RESET PASSWORD FORM
                        //
                        // https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-wordpress-user-flow-part-3-password-reset--cms-23811

                        $color_notifications = woffice_get_settings_option('color_notifications');                          
                        echo'<div class="infobox fa-meh-o" style="background-color: '.$color_notifications.';">';

                            if ( isset( $_REQUEST['errors'] ) ) {
                                $error_codes = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['errors'] );

                                foreach ( $error_codes as $error_code ) {
                                    switch ( $error_code ) {
                                        // Lost password
                                        case 'empty_username':
                                            $message_error =  __( 'You need to enter your email address to continue.', 'woffice' );
                                        case 'invalid_email':
                                        case 'invalidcombo':
                                            $message_error = __( 'There are no users registered with this email address.', 'woffice' );
                                        // Reset password
                                        /*case 'expiredkey':
                                        case 'invalidkey':
                                            $message_error = __( 'The password reset link you used is not valid anymore.', 'personalize-login' );
                                        case 'password_reset_mismatch':
                                            $message_error = __( "The two passwords you entered don't match.", 'personalize-login' );
                                        case 'password_reset_empty':
                                            $message_error = __( "Sorry, we don't accept empty passwords.", 'personalize-login' );
                                        default:
                                            break;*/
                                    }
                                    echo'<p>'.$message_error.'</p>';
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo'<span class="infobox-head">'. __('Forgot Your Password ? ','woffice').'</span>';
                                echo'<p>'. __('Enter your email address and we\'ll send you a link you can use to pick a new password.','woffice') .'</p>';
                            }

                        echo'</div>';

                        ?>

                            <form id="lostpasswordform" action="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url(); ?>" class="clearfix" method="post">
                                <p class="form-row">
                                    <label for="user_login"><?php _e( 'Email', 'woffice' ); ?>
                                    <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login">
                                </p>

                                <p class="lostpassword-submit">
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="lostpassword-button"
                                           value="<?php _e( 'Reset Password', 'woffice' ); ?>"/>
                                </p>
                            </form>

                        <?php 

                    } else {
                        //
                        // THE LOGIN FORM
                        //
                        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['checkemail'] ) && $_REQUEST['checkemail'] == 'confirm' ) : ?>
                            <p class="login-info">
                            <?php _e( 'Check your email for a link to reset your password.', 'woffice' ); ?>
                        </p>
                        <?php endif; 

                        $aft_login = woffice_get_settings_option('aft_login'); 
                        $custom_redirect_url = woffice_get_settings_option('custom_redirect_url'); 
                        if($aft_login == "custom") {
                            $redirect_url = $custom_redirect_url;
                        } elseif ($aft_login == "previous") {
                            //Get the redirect url where redirect to
                            $previous_url = (isset($_GET['redirect_to']) && !empty($_GET['redirect_to'])) ? urldecode($_GET['redirect_to']) : null;

                            if(!is_null($previous_url)) {
                                //Get the current url
                                $http = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
                                $current_url = $http . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

                                $current_url_noparam = explode("?", $current_url);
                                $previous_url_noparam = explode("?", $previous_url);

                                //Check if the previous url is the same of current one or if it hosted on another address
                                if ($current_url_noparam[0] == $previous_url_noparam[0] || strpos($previous_url, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) === false){
                                    $redirect_url = home_url();
                                } else {
                                    $redirect_url = $previous_url;
                                }
                                //$redirect_url = site_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                            } else {
                                $redirect_url = home_url();
                            }
                        } else {
                            $redirect_url = home_url();
                        }

                        $login_args = array(
                            'redirect' => $redirect_url, 
                            'id_username' => 'user',
                            'id_password' => 'pass',
                        );
                        wp_login_form( $login_args );
                        // LOST PASSWORD LINK 
                        $login_rest_password = woffice_get_settings_option('login_rest_password'); 
                        if ($login_rest_password == "yep"){
                            echo '<a href="'. wp_lostpassword_url() .'" class="password-lost">'. __('Lost Password','woffice') .'</a>'; 
                        }

                    }
                    ?>

                    <?php 
                    /* REGISTER FORM */
                    $user_can_register = apply_filters('woffice_users_can_register', get_option('users_can_register'));
                    if ($user_can_register == '1'){
                        $register_message = woffice_get_settings_option('register_message'); 
                        echo '<div id="register-wrapper">';
                        echo '<p>'.$register_message.'</p>';

                        // Check for paid membership pro
                        $register_pmp = woffice_get_settings_option('register_pmp'); 
                        if ( $register_pmp == "yep" && function_exists("pmpro_getOption") ){
                            $register_page = get_permalink(pmpro_getOption("levels_page_id"));
                            echo '<a href="'.$register_page.'" class="btn btn-default bp-ajaxr" id="register-trigger"><i class="fa fa-sign-in bp-ajaxr"></i> '. __('Sign Up','woffice') .'</a>';            
                        } else {
                            echo '<a href="#register-form" class="btn btn-default bp-ajaxr" id="register-trigger"><i class="fa fa-sign-in bp-ajaxr"></i> '. __('Sign Up','woffice') .'</a>';
                        }

                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<div id="register-loader" class="intern-padding woffice-loader"><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i></div>';

                        echo '<div id="goback-trigger"><a href="#loginform" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> '. __('Go back','woffice') .'</a></div>';
                    }
                    ?>


                    <?php // DISPLAY WORDPRESS LINK ? 
                    $login_wordpress = woffice_get_settings_option('login_wordpress'); 
                    if ($login_wordpress == "yep"):
                    ?>
                        <footer>
                            <p>
                                <?php _e("Proudly powered by","woffice"); ?> 
                                <a href="https://wordpress.org/" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.svg" alt="wordpress logo">
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </footer>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

            </section>
            <!-- END CONTENT -->

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JAVSCRIPTS BELOW AND FILES LOADED BY WORDPRESS -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (jQuery('#success-register').length > 0) {
            jQuery('#register-loader').slideDown();
            jQuery("#register-form, #goback-trigger").hide();
            jQuery("#loginform, #register-wrapper,a.password-lost").hide();
            function show_login() {
                jQuery("#loginform, #register-wrapper,a.password-lost").show();
                jQuery('#register-loader').slideUp();
            }
            setTimeout(show_login, 2000);
            <?php $register_autoredirect = woffice_get_settings_option('register_autoredirect');
            if($register_autoredirect == "yep") : ?>
                var NewUser = jQuery('#success-register').data('user');
                if (NewUser) {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url: "<?php echo get_site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                        data: {"action" : "WofficeRegisterRedirect", "user_id" : NewUser, "security" : "<?php echo wp_create_nonce( "WofficeRegisterRedirectNonce" ); ?>"},
                        success:function(returnval){
                            jQuery(returnval).appendTo("body");
                            jQuery(".woffice-ajax-main").show();
                            function RedirectAfterLogin() {
                                window.location.replace("<?php echo get_site_url() ?>");
                            }
                            setTimeout(RedirectAfterLogin, 2000);
                        },
                    });
                }
            <?php endif; ?>
        }
        jQuery("#register-loader, #register-form, #goback-trigger").hide();
        jQuery("#register-trigger").on('click', function(){
            jQuery('#register-loader').slideDown();
            jQuery("#loginform, #register-wrapper,a.password-lost").hide();
            function show_register() {
                jQuery("#register-form, #goback-trigger").show();
                jQuery('#register-loader').slideUp();
            }
            setTimeout(show_register, 1000);
        });
        jQuery("#goback-trigger a").on('click', function(){
            jQuery('#register-loader').slideDown();
            jQuery("#register-form, #goback-trigger").hide();
            function show_login() {
                jQuery("#loginform, #register-wrapper,a.password-lost").show();
                jQuery('#register-loader').slideUp();
            }
            setTimeout(show_login, 1000);
        });
        var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');
        if (hash == 'register-form') {
            if (jQuery('#success-register').length  == 0) {
                jQuery('#register-loader').slideDown();
                jQuery("#loginform, #register-wrapper,a.password-lost").hide();
                function show_register() {
                    jQuery("#register-form").show();
                    jQuery('#register-loader').slideUp();
                }
                setTimeout(show_register, 1000);
            }
        }
    </script>

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the template file change the followign stuff

```
<div id="woffice-login-left">
     <video>Video Tag goes here</video>
     <?php echo get_search_form();?>     
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit please.

Comment: You get rid of $login_revslider because you don't need the slider in the template. Remove those logic and have a static content as mentioned above in the div tag which has id "woffice-login-left".